# Why are these two questions "linked"?

Tags: support, questions

When looking at [this question about Monster Hunter World](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/326201/what-are-the-locations-and-conditions-for-catching-the-rare-pets), the sidebar on the right shows a single "Linked" question, which is [this question about Apex Legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/347137/how-can-i-find-out-weapons-and-their-stats). The opposite is also true, with the Monster Hunter World question showing as a "Linked" question of the one about Apex Legends.

How did this happen? Can this be undone? It looks confusing and not at all helpful in this case.

Comment: That second question could be closed and deleted if someone hadn’t posted a bounty to prevent it from being closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/347137/how-can-i-find-out-weapons-and-their-stats#comment489336_347137) on the second question links to the first.  That's why the two questions are linked, even though they have nothing much in common.

Comment: Ah, I feel silly for not noticing that link.